# Get gps location once for 5 mins android Eclipse source code

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, location

Some once can give me a Eclipse source code to build an App android to get gps location once for 5 mins android Eclipse source code
Thanks to much !

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService (LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() { }     
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, intervall , distance, listener);
```

The interval parameter is used to get location updates between specified time in milliseconds.